# How can I set environment variables for a different user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to get 2 docker containers started and linked together with a rails app.  This app relies on these environment variables:

```
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT
```

When I do env as root I'm getting:

```
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.2
```

When I run it under root I'm not getting any problem and it works.  However the application runs as app user.  When I do env as app:

```
root@f80f94948393:/home/app# sudo -u app env
```

I'm not seeing those variables.  I googled around and have altered these files already:

/etc/environment

```
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR="172.17.0.2"
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT="5432"
```

/home/app/.profile

```
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT="5432";export POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR="172.17.0.2";export POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR
```

/home/app/.bashrc

```
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT="5432";export POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR="172.17.0.2";export POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR
```

But nothing seems to help.  The variables aren't showing up with app user.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how you run the program as non-root, bu when you use
sudo, you may use -E (see: man sudo) that should preserve env.

Otherwise you may add those variables into system-wide .bashrc (/etc/bash.bashrc) if you use bash at all.